# Probability of Event A or B occurring or Both

Tags: probability

Given a randomly subject visited a dentist or a surgeon (or both), what is the probability that he/she visited a dentist?
Data: 40% visited a dentist, 60% visited a surgeon and 20% visited both.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Can you, say, compute the $4$ probabilities {dentist only,surgeon only, both, neither}?

Comment: I've been stuck in this one since early today.

Comment: Ok...I'll do "surgeon only".  Just to fix concepts, lets say there are exactly 100 people here.  Then 60 of them saw a surgeon.  We also know that 20 people saw both.   Those are counted amongst the 60...so we must have 60-20 = 40 people who only saw a surgeon  Thus the probability of seeing a surgeon only is $40\%$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D$ be the event of visiting a dentist and $S$ be the event of visiting a
Surgeon, we see that what we are trying to find in the model is
$$P(D | D \vee S)
= \frac{P(D \wedge (D \vee S))}{P(D \vee S)}.$$
We know by inclusion exclusion that
$$P(D \vee S) = P(D) + P(S) - P(D \wedge S) = .4 + 6 - .2 = .8.$$
We see that, by distributivity of the $\wedge$ operator,
$$P(D \wedge (D \vee S))
= P((D \wedge D) \vee (D \wedge S))
= P(D \vee (D \wedge S)),$$
which by inclusion-exclusion is
$$=P(D) + P(D \wedge S) - P(D \wedge D \wedge S) = P(D)  = .4$$
Hence,
$$P(D | D \vee S) = \frac{.4}{.8} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: *Remark:* As $D\wedge(D\vee S) \equiv D$ by the absorption rule, then we *immediately* have $\mathsf P(D\wedge(D\vee S) = \mathsf P(D)$. $~$ Saves a line or two.

Answer (score 1):

I find it clarifies things to work with exactly $100$ people (you could just as well take percents, but this seems more definite).

We have $40$ people who saw a dentist.  As exactly $20$ people saw both a dentist and a surgeon, we must have $20$ people who saw only the dentist.

We have $60$ people who saw a surgeon.  As exactly $20$ people saw both a dentist and a surgeon, we must have $40$ people who saw only the surgeon.

As given, $20$ people saw both.

It follows that $80$ people saw one or the other (or both) and that $20$ people saw neither.

We are told that our random subject saw at least one, hence is amongst the $80$.  Of those $80$, we know that $40$ saw a dentist.  Hence the probability that this random person saw a dentist is $\frac {40}{80}=\frac 12$